# Why in Canvas(JS) toDataUrl() doesn't work after drawImage()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage, todataurl

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    canvas.width=img.width;
    canvas.height=img.height;
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
  }
  img.src="2.jpg";
  function compress(){
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg",0.5);
    document.getElementById("img").src=dataURL;
  }          
  setTimeout(compress,1000);
</script>
```

I've tried to use as example `fillRect()` instead of `drawImage()`. So it works normally... I'm sure that reason is `drawImage()`

Comment: In the code you are testing, what is the *real* URL of the image? In particular, is it from the same domain as the page the code is in?

Comment: Also, you really should put the call to "compress" in the image "onload" callback; you're relying on the image HTTP request to finish within 1 second, which may or may not actually happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image URL (the original URL, not the data URL) is from a different domain than that of the page where the code runs, then the canvas will be *tainted* when you draw the image to it, and you wont be able to get the pixels back out. That's a security measure. Thus if you're testing on jsfiddle and you're using `http://placekitten.com/100/100` urls to test, it won't work.

Note that most modern browsers do not consider two `file://` URLs to share a domain, so if you're running the test from local files, it won't work.

Comment: Actually, images and page are on the same domain, and there is no "file://" in URL's. That's why your solution don't work =(

Comment: @user3560634 well you'll have to supply more information then, or try getting rid of the `setTimeout()` hack because that could also cause the problem.

Comment: @user3560634 [Here is your code in a test page I wrote, and it works properly.](http://gutfullofbeer.net/imgtst/) All I changed was to get rid of the timeout and move the call to "compress" into the image "load" handler, after the image is drawn to the canvas.